# Runtime error 424 With VBA to AutoCAD Code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to draw in AutoCAD, using data from an Excel sheet, by VBA code.

I found a code and ticked the references:

- AutoCAD Library
- AutoCAD Object/DBX
- AutoCAD Focus for VBA

Here is the code to draw a circle:

```
Sub AddCircle()
    ' Define the center point
    Dim ptCen(0 To 2) As Double
    ptCen(0) = 2: ptCen(1) = 3: ptCen(2) = 0#

    ' Create a Circle object in model space
    Dim circObj As AcadCircle
    Set circObj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCircle(ptCen, 4.25)

    ThisDrawing.Application.ZoomAll
End Sub
```

I got Runtime error 424. It seems that I missed some object.

Comment: If that code is in Excel, then Excel has no idea what `ThisDrawing` is.

Comment: What line of code throws the error? What have you done to research/fix it?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful: http://entercad.ru/acadauto.en/. Try making a new instance of the AcadCircle object, then call the AddCircle method of that Class.

Comment: @GSerg , Thank you It works properly now :)

Answer (score 1):

To draw something in AutoCAD (must be opened) from Excel you must add reference Tools->References and add [**AutoCAD 20xx Type Library**]
and insert this in your code:

```
Dim app
On Error Resume Next
    Set app = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If (app Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
```

then refer to the active document

```
Dim doc
Set doc = app.ActiveDocument
```

now you can add circle with change *ThisDrawing* with **doc**

```
' Create a Circle object in model space
Dim circObj As AcadCircle
Set circObj = doc.ModelSpace.AddCircle(ptCen, 4.25)

doc.Application.ZoomAll
```